# Error : Using Microsoft WebService.dll to canonicalize XML with Delphi7

Tags: xml, web-services, delphi

I'm modifying an old project with Delphi7 to add using certificate and signing. After doing some search I found [XML Canonicalization Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd815358(v=vs.85)) but I couldn't get any of theses functions worked :

- WsStartReaderCanonicalization / WsEndReaderCanonicalization
- WsStartWriterCanonicalization / WsEndWriterCanonicalization

these functions are included in [Microsoft WebServices.dll](https://learn.microsoft.com/sk-sk/windows/win32/api/webservices/) which I found a headers translation for it on
[Github](https://github.com/delphiunderground/WWSAPI) but I still no luck. Here is the code I tested :

`{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
program XmlBufferExample;

//This example shows some use of the xml buffer APIs.
//Original C++ code from Microsoft :
//https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd819131(v=vs.85).aspx

uses
  Windows, Sysutils, Classes,
  webservices in 'webservices.pas';

Procedure PrintError(errorCode:HRESULT; error:PWS_ERROR);
var
  hr:HRESULT;
  errorCount,i:ULONG;
  str:WS_STRING;
  s:string;
begin
  writeln(Format('Failure: errorCode=0x8%.x',[errorCode]));

  if (errorCode=E_INVALIDARG) or (errorCode=WS_E_INVALID_OPERATION) then
  begin
    // Correct use of the APIs should never generate these errors
    writeln('The error was due to an invalid use of an API. This is likely due to a bug in the program.');
    exit;
  end;

  hr:=NOERROR;
  if (error<>nil) then
  begin
    hr:=WsGetErrorProperty(error, WS_ERROR_PROPERTY_STRING_COUNT, @errorCount, sizeof(errorCount));
    if (hr=NOERROR) and (errorCount>0) then
      for i:=0 to errorCount-1 do
      begin
        hr:=WsGetErrorString(error, i, @str);
        if (hr=NOERROR) then
        begin
          s:=copy(str.chars,1,str.length);
          writeln(s);
        end else
          errorCount:=i; //exit for
      end;
  end;
  if (hr<>NOERROR) then
    writeln(Format('Could not get error string (errorCode=0x8%.x)',[hr]));
end;

var
  MyCallbackStatus : Cardinal;
  Found : BOOL;
  Mybuffer:PWS_XML_BUFFER = nil;
const
  HeapSize = 24 * 1024;  //24 kb

function MyCallback(callbackState : pointer; buffer : PWS_BYTES; count : ULONG;
                     asyncContext : PWS_ASYNC_CONTEXT; error : PWS_ERROR):HRESULT; stdcall;
var
  S : AnsiString;
begin
//debuging start
  Writeln('Inside MyCallback :');
  Writeln('MyCallbackStatus :', IntToStr(MyCallbackStatus));
  if Assigned(error) then PrintError(0, error);
//debuging end

  if Assigned(buffer) then
    SetString(S, PAnsiChar(buffer.bytes), buffer.length);

  Writeln(s);
end;

var
  hr:HRESULT;
  error:PWS_ERROR;
  heap:PWS_HEAP;
  buffer:PWS_XML_BUFFER;
  writer:PWS_XML_WRITER;
  reader:PWS_XML_READER;
  newXml:pointer;
  newXmlLength:ULONG;
  xml:ansistring;
  ExitCode:integer;
  Stream : TMemoryStream;
begin
  error:=nil;
  heap:=nil;
  buffer:=nil;
  writer:=nil;
  reader:=nil;
  newXml:=nil;
  newXmlLength:=0;

  // Create an error object for storing rich error information
  hr := WsCreateError(nil,
                      0,
                      @error);

  if (hr=NOERROR) then
  begin
    // Create a heap to store deserialized data
    hr := WsCreateHeap(2048,   //maxSize
                       512,    //trimSize
                       nil,
                       0,
                       @heap,
                       error);
  end;

  if hr=NOERROR then
  begin
    // Create an XML writer
    hr := WsCreateWriter(nil,
                         0,
                         @writer,
                         error);
  end;

  if hr=NOERROR then
  begin
    // Create an XML reader
    hr := WsCreateReader(nil,
                         0,
                         @reader,
                         error);
  end;

  // Some xml to read and write
  xml:='<a><b>1</b><c>2</c></a>';

  if hr=NOERROR then
  begin
    hr:=WsReadXmlBufferFromBytes(reader,
                                 nil,
                                 nil,
                                 0,
                                 PAnsiChar(xml), //@xml[1],
                                 length(xml),
                                 heap,
                                 @buffer,
                                 error);

  end;

  if hr=NOERROR then
  begin
    hr:=WsWriteXmlBufferToBytes(writer,
                                buffer,
                                nil,
                                nil,
                                0,
                                heap,
                                @newXml,
                                @newXmlLength,
                                error);
  end;

  if hr=NOERROR then
  begin
    writeln('new xml :');
    writeln(copy(PAnsiChar(newXml),1,newXmlLength));
    writeln;
    ExitCode:=0;
  end;

  //----------------------------------------
  //My test start
  //----------------------------------------
  if hr=NOERROR then
  begin
    if Assigned(reader) then
    begin
      WsFreeReader(reader);
      reader := nil;
    end;
    hr := WsCreateReader(nil, 0, @reader, error);

    if Assigned(heap) then
    begin
      WsFreeHeap(heap);
      heap := nil;
    end;
    hr := WsCreateHeap(3 * HeapSize, 512, nil, 0, @heap, error);

    if hr=NOERROR then
    begin
      //load xml file
      Stream := TMemoryStream.Create();
      try
        Stream.LoadFromFile('Z:\zatca-einvoicing-sdk\test\100030.xml');
        SetString(xml, PChar(Stream.Memory), Stream.Size);
        Writeln;
        Writeln('-------------------------------');
        Writeln('XML File size is ' + IntToStr(Stream.Size) + ' Bytes');
      finally
        Stream.Free();
      end;

      hr:=WsReadXmlBufferFromBytes(reader, nil, nil, 0, PAnsiChar(xml), length(xml), heap, @buffer, error);
    end;

(*
according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/webservices/nf-webservices-wsstartreadercanonicalization
The usage pattern for canonicalization is:
  1)  Move the Reader to the element where canonicalization begins.
  2)  Call WsStartReaderCanonicalization.
  3)  Move the Reader forward to the end position.
  4)  Call WsEndReaderCanonicalization.

*)
// Step1: Move the Reader to the element where canonicalization begins.  [this gives an error]
    if hr=NOERROR then
      hr := WsMoveReader(reader, WS_MOVE_TO_PARENT_ELEMENT, @Found, error);

// Step2 : Call WsStartReaderCanonicalization.
    MyCallbackStatus := 0;
    if hr=NOERROR then
      hr:=WsStartReaderCanonicalization(reader, MyCallback, @MyCallbackStatus, nil, 0, error);

// Step3: Move the Reader forward to the end position.  [this gives an error]
    if hr=NOERROR then
      hr := WsMoveReader(reader, WS_MOVE_TO_EOF, @Found, error);

// Step4 : Call WsEndReaderCanonicalization  [this will call MyCallback]
    if hr=NOERROR then
      hr := WsEndReaderCanonicalization(reader, error);
  end;

  //----------------------------------------
  //My test End
  //----------------------------------------

  if hr <> NOERROR then
  begin
    PrintError(hr,error);
    ExitCode:=-1;
  end;


  if writer<>nil then WsFreeWriter(writer);
  if reader<>nil then WsFreeReader(reader);
  if heap<>nil then WsFreeHeap(heap);
  if error<>nil then WsFreeError(error);

  Readln;
  halt(exitcode);
end.`

As you can see in code, the function WsMoveReader() gives an error. When I delete the call to WsMoveReader() the code complete with no errors but when MyCallback is called, the buffer parameter is nil. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Far too much code. Please reduce it to a [mre] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Your code is far from being minimal - it even recreates `writer` and `heap`, making the previous instances meaningless. After eliminating the errors (and warnings) I wasn't able to achieve your goal either - I hope you read [the page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/webservices/nf-webservices-wsstartreadercanonicalization) fully: "_It is not valid to call WsMoveReader or WsSetReaderPosition on a Reader between calls to WsStartReaderCanonicalization and WsEndReaderCanonicalization._" So it can be expected to fail.

Comment: @AmigoJack at the top of the page they say 
The usage pattern for canonicalization is:
    Move the Reader to the element where canonicalization begins.
    Call WsStartReaderCanonicalization.
    Move the Reader forward to the end position.
    Call WsEndReaderCanonicalization.
During this process the canonical bytes are written to the specified writeCallback

Comment: Obviously they mean something different, which is also the reason why they didn't explicitly mention functions for those steps. Please use at least quotation marks.

Comment: @AmigoJack English is not my language so forgive my bad English. Please reopen the other question you closed. Can you tell me how can I close this question?

Comment: Take the [tour] to finally learn how this website works, why Qs are closed and how they can be reopened. Without [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74283999/edit) it it won't happen anyway. Mind the differences between questions, answers and comments. English is "_not my language_", too - if my skills are too low to understand rules and guidelines I would look for a different website instead of forcing my way in.

Comment: @AmigoJack you have been using this website for over 5 years, while I'm still new here just one week so I need more time to get familiar with all the rules. I think the main objective of this site is to provide an opportunity for people to help each other, and I think you are not helping me by talking about my skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts, I finally found the answer to my question. This solution is somewhat primitive, but it performs the required function. Here is my code.

The following is a dummy function but the code don't run without it. I tried to use `nil` instead of it but failed.

```pascal
uses
  Windows, Sysutils, Classes, webservices, wcrypt2, ncrypt;

//   A user-defined callback used by the WS_XML_WRITER to write a buffer to some destination.
function MyCallback(callbackState : pointer; buffer : PWS_BYTES; count : ULONG;
                     asyncContext : PWS_ASYNC_CONTEXT; error : PWS_ERROR):HRESULT; stdcall;
begin
  Result := 0;
end;
```

The canonical function.

```pascal
function CanonicalXML(xml : string; Exclusive:Boolean=True; WithComment:Boolean=True) : string;
const
  HeapSize = 128 * 1024;  //128 KB for test
  Exclusives : array[Boolean, Boolean] of Integer = (
    (WS_INCLUSIVE_XML_CANONICALIZATION_ALGORITHM, WS_INCLUSIVE_WITH_COMMENTS_XML_CANONICALIZATION_ALGORITHM),
    (WS_EXCLUSIVE_XML_CANONICALIZATION_ALGORITHM, WS_EXCLUSIVE_WITH_COMMENTS_XML_CANONICALIZATION_ALGORITHM)
  );
  
var
  hr:HRESULT;
  heap:PWS_HEAP;
  buffer:PWS_XML_BUFFER;
  writer:PWS_XML_WRITER;
  reader:PWS_XML_READER;
  newXml:pointer;
  newXmlLength :ULONG;
  MyCallbackStatus : Cardinal;
  CanProp : WS_XML_CANONICALIZATION_PROPERTY;
  PtrCanProp : PWS_XML_CANONICALIZATION_PROPERTY;
  Algorithm : ULONG;
begin
  buffer := nil;
  writer := nil;
  reader := nil;
  
  //Setup algorithm used in canonicalization. 
  Algorithm := Exclusives[Exclusive, WithComment];
  CanProp.id := WS_XML_CANONICALIZATION_PROPERTY_ALGORITHM ;
  CanProp.value := @Algorithm;
  CanProp.valueSize := SizeOf(Algorithm);
  PtrCanProp := @CanProp;   
   
  hr := WsCreateReader(nil, 0, @reader, nil);     // Create an XML reader

  if hr=NOERROR then
    hr := WsCreateWriter(nil, 0, @writer, nil);   // Create an XML writer

  if (hr=NOERROR) then
    hr := WsCreateHeap(HeapSize, 512, nil, 0, @heap, nil); // Create a heap to store data

  if hr=NOERROR then    //read data into buffer
    hr:=WsReadXmlBufferFromBytes(reader, nil, nil, 0, PAnsiChar(xml), length(xml), heap, @buffer, nil);

  if hr=NOERROR then
    hr:=WsWriteXmlBufferToBytes(writer, buffer, nil, nil, 0, heap, @newXml, @newXmlLength, nil);

  if hr=NOERROR then
    hr := WsStartWriterCanonicalization(writer, MyCallback, @MyCallbackStatus, PtrCanProp, 1, nil);
  if hr=NOERROR then
    hr := WsEndWriterCanonicalization(writer, nil);

  if hr=NOERROR then
    SetString(Result, PAnsiChar(newXml), newXmlLength);

  //Free created objects
  if Assigned(writer) then WsFreeWriter(writer);
  if Assigned(reader) then WsFreeReader(reader);
  if Assigned(heap) then WsFreeHeap(heap);
end;
```

**Note:**
In some cases this function returns "#10" before and after the actual result, so the result must be modified like :

```pascal
SetString(Result, PAnsiChar(newXml), newXmlLength);
Result := Trim(Result);
```